# How to execute the saltstack minion

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to install the Nginx package by using salt minion.  But, I am unable to install. 
I tried to write an `.sls` file in a new directory called Nginx like below:

`/salt/states/base/nginx/init.sls`:

```
nginx:
  pkg:
    - installed
  service:
    - running
    - watch:
      - pkg: nginx
```

I had written `top.sls` like below:

```
base:
  'saltminion*':
    - nginx
```

I executed the below command:

```
salt '*' state.highstate
```

and I am getting output like below:

```
ubuntu:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found
     Changes:   

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total:     1
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

In your `top.sls`, your target is `saltminion*` wheres after you execute `salt '*' state.highstate`, i can see that the id of the minion that responds is `ubuntu`. There is no top file being sent to the minion having name `ubuntu`. So either change the target in your `top.sls` to `ubuntu` instead of `saltminion*`; or change the id of your minion to `saltminion1` or `saltminion2`; or add another target in your `top.sls` like this:

```
base:
  'saltminion*':
    - nginx
  'ubuntu':
    - nginx
```

And try again after that.

Comment: Your top file is located here, by default:
/srv/salt/top.sls